# My schema is nullable but still giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Schema is given below:

```
root
 |-- reviewText: string (nullable = true)
```

Selected the row to perform the operation

```
val extracted_reviews = sql("select reviewText from book").collect
```

had loaded AFINN here

```
val reviewSenti = extracted_reviews.map(reviewText => { val reviewWordsSentiment = reviewText(1).toString.split(" ").map(word => {
  var senti: Int = 0;
  if (AFINN.lookup(word.toLowerCase()).length > 0) {
    senti = AFINN.lookup(word.toLowerCase())(0)
  }
  senti
})
  val reviewSentiment = reviewWordsSentiment.sum
  (reviewSentiment ,reviewText.toString)
})
```

I am already having `reviewText` as null in schema so why it is giving this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.get(rows.scala:200)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.apply(Row.scala:157)
  at 
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
  ... 52 elided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collect()` returns `Array[Row]` so to get the value from it you can use `reviewText.getString(0)`

```
val reviewSenti = extracted_reviews.map(reviewText => 
    val reviewWordsSentiment = reviewText.getString(0).split(" ").map(...)
)
```